# $\lfloor \sqrt{D}\rfloor>q_{l-1}\implies$no odd solution to $x^2-Dy^2=\pm4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, continued-fractions, pell-type-equations

I try to show that $a_0=\lfloor \sqrt{D}\rfloor>q_{l-1}$ (or $\frac{q_{l-1}}{2}$ if $q_{l-1}$ is even) **implies** that there is no **odd** solution to the Pell equation $$x^2-Dy^2=\pm4$$

$D$ is a positive integer, $D\equiv 5 \mod 8$, $l$ is the length of the period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{D}$, $q_{l-1}$ is the denominator of the $l^{th}$ convergent and $p_{l-1}^2-q_{l-1}^2D=\pm1$ (from which **even** solutions can be derived)

I tried using the standard *convergents* (in)equalities as well as the *fundamental unit* properties but got nowhere. I suspect it to be true, but I might be wrong. Anything is know about this?

OEIS references [A107996](https://oeis.org/A107996) and [A107999](https://oeis.org/A107999)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick:

numbers $D\equiv 5 \mod 8$ that have an odd solution to $x^2-Dy^2=\pm4$ will have this propery (except for $D=5)$: $$(\frac{p_{\epsilon}+q_{\epsilon}\sqrt{D}}{2})^3=p_{l-1}+q_{l-1}\sqrt{D}$$ where $(p_{\epsilon},q_{\epsilon})$ is the smallest solution.
We have then $q_{l-1}=\frac{(p_{\epsilon}^2\mp1)q_{\epsilon}}{2}$ and from the original equation: $p_{\epsilon}^2=Dq_{\epsilon}^2\pm4$, this leads to
$$q_{l-1}=\frac{Dq_{\epsilon}^3\pm4q_{\epsilon}\mp q_{\epsilon}}{2}<\sqrt{D}$$
Since $D\ge13$ (we need to exclude $5$ which is a special case), this is not possible even with $q_{\epsilon}=1$

Note: Since $\lfloor \sqrt{D}\rfloor\ne q_{l-1}$, we can drop the floor function.